# RHEL8でImportError: No module named yumを解決したい

Tags: python, yum, rhel

RHEL8で以下のコマンドを実行

```
python -c ’import yum, pprint; yb =yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumbar,width=1)’
```

実行結果(エラー)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>, line 1, in<module>"
ImportError: No module named yum
```

Comment: 実行している python は OS 標準のものかは分かりますか？ (自身でソース等から個別にインストールしたバージョン等は使っていたりしますか？)

Comment: yumは RHEL7までで RHEL8からdnfに変わったはずなので, `import dnf` かも？

Comment: @oriri import dnfで実行すると同じくImportError No module named dnfとエラーが出ました。

Comment: @cubick 個別にインストールしたpython2.7.18を使っています。

Comment: OS標準の (システムが利用する) Platform-Python というのがあり, それが yumなり dnfなり使うはず(使えるはず) だと思われ。適当に用意した Pythonでは `sys.path`合ってないはずで読み込めないし, そもそもバージョン合ってなくて動かないかもしれない。  
質問と同等の表示を行うならシステム内の Platform-Python 探すのが(たぶん) よいのでは？

Comment: @cubick  Platform-Pythonを使うように設定するとpython command not foundのエラーが出ました。。

Answer (score 0):

まずバージョンを指定しないpythonコマンドをPython3.6に設定する。

```
alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3
```

その後以下のコマンドを実行する。

```
python -c 'import dnf, pprint; db = dnf.dnf.Base(); pprint.pprint(db.conf.substitutions,width=1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

[RHEL 8 の導入における検討事項 - API の可用性](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index#_availability_of_apis)に

> **YUM v3** が提供する以前の Python API は利用できなくなりました。**YUM v4** (DNF Python API) が提供する安定し、完全に対応する新しい API に、使用しているプラグインおよびスクリプトを移行することが推奨されます。新しい DNF Python API のドキュメントは、「DNF API Reference」により提供されます。

と説明されているように、`import yum`は使えなくなり`import dnf`とした上で、DNF APIを使用する必要があります。

なお、RHEL7のYUM Python APIはyumパッケージに含まれますし、RHEL8のDNF Python APIもpython3-dnfパッケージに含まれます。そのため、「個別にインストールしたpython2.7.18」では扱うことができません。